# HREF to a .doc file works... an HREF to a .docx does not

Tags: html, xhtml, href, doctype

Strange... When i create an HREF to a .doc, the browser behaves correctly and onclick allows the user to download the file.

If I have an HREF to a .docx, it doesn't prompt to the user to download the file but shows a "The page cannot be found" error page at the url of the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a web server configuration issue. Do you know what web server is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just figured it out... It's an IIS MIME type header setting that needs to be added:
.doc
application/msword

Answer (score 1):

Not to overlook the most obvious answer, but the file does exist, and the link is correct?

Comment: Ya it does. I confirmed that.